# list environment where some items don't start new paragraph

Tags: macros, lists, programming

I want to use a list-like environment, but I need to put some short items on the same line. The user interface will be something like:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item First very long element
\item* shrot 
\item short
\itme Last very long element
\end{enumerate}
```

The output should look like this:

1. First very long element
2. short 3. short
3. Last very long element

I marked the item with a *, but it can be other macro name; or an environment that contains the short elements.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do specifically this? Having the items bunch in this way will violate the expectations of almost all people reading it, about how lists should be formatted. --- Have you considered making your entire list inline? This could be achieved using custom list environments, which would allow you to switch quickly to a traditional list format if you wished to compare the results.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap I now, but I am duplicating a layout done in a graphical program. This problem arises in a bunch of solutions to some math exercises. It is not my preferred way to layout it, but I have to use as less space as reasonable.

Comment: Perhaps you'd be interested in the `tasks` package, that is originally designed for the layout of solutions to exercices in  horizontally enumerated lists. It has a `\task*` command that allows for the specific item to use the remaining space on the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enumitem` has always met my needs for lists. However, I'm not sure it is the best option here.

[multienum](http://ctan.org/pkg/multenum) seems designed to do just what you want.

It provides an environment `multienumerate` within which you can use commands such as `\mitemx{}` to define a line with a single item, `\mitemxx{}{}` for a line with 2 and so on. You can also say something like `\mitemxxxo{}{}{}` if you have 3 items and want them to be spaced as if there was a phantom fourth item rather than spacing them evenly. This can be used to get things aligned nicely if required.

Here is an example which is based on the idea of a 4 column layout:

[image: 4 columns aligned]

Although hardly wise, you can even create enumerations in which things are *not* nicely aligned, if that happens to tickle your fancy. Don't try this at home:

[image: non-aligned appearances]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{multienum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
Now we turn to a listing of things in themselves.
\begin{multienumerate}
  \mitemx{Our conceptual understanding of space which must shape the way in which we understand spatial relationships.}
  \mitemxxxo{Being 1}{Being 2}{Being 3}
  \mitemxxxx{First Being}{Second}{Third}{Fourth}
  \mitemxx{This is a ponderous one.}{This less so.}
  \mitemx{Our concept of time gives rise to a number of extremely perplexing antimonies.}
\end{multienumerate}
Now we turn to a listing of appearances.
\begin{multienumerate}
  \mitemx{\kant[2]}
  \mitemxxx{Appearance 1}{Appearance 2}{Appearance 3}
  \mitemxxxx{First Appearance}{Second}{Third}{Fourth}
  \mitemxxxxx{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}
  \mitemx{The phenomena give rise to a number of extremely perplexing antimonies concerning the noumena.}
  \mitemxx{This is a somewhat ponderous appearance.}{This is not really any less so.}
  \mitemxxxxx{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}
\end{multienumerate}
\end{document}
```

The package appears to support rows of up to 5 items, although the documentation says it supports fewer than this.

Answer (score 1):

The `enumitem` package version 3.0 provide inline lists (horizontal lists), for their use just add `inline` in the options when calling the package, this provides the environments
`enumerate*`, `itemize*` and `description*`  they can be used as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\newcommand{\inline}[1]{\stepcounter{enumi}
\def\c{\theenumi}
\begin{enumerate*}[label=\arabic*. ,start=\c]
\item #1
\end{enumerate*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First very long element
\item short \inline{short} \inline{short}
\item Last very long element
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```